# Not getting all Image URLs from Product page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from [This](https://www.uspens.co/ws/ws.dll/PrDtl?UID=31818&SPC=wgftb-kzzro) URL. I have applied the below logic.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


try:
    html = urlopen("https://www.uspens.co/p/WGFTB-KZZRO/premium-black-tube")

except HTTPError as e:
    print(e)

except URLError:
    print("Server down or incorrect domain")

else:
    res = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html5lib")

tag = res.find("iframe")
frame_url = tag['src']
print(frame_url)

frame = urlopen(frame_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(frame.read(), "html5lib")

#Product Image
img = soup.find_all("img", class_ = 'img-responsive')
print(img)

for u in img:
    img_url = 'https://www.uspens.co' + u["src"]
    print(img_url)
```

There are two images of the product. But I am getting only one Image URL, which is correct. The other Image URL is either wrong or the same as 1st URL.

***How do i extend this code for getting all image URLs of product from product page?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the source of the images at the src Attribute:

```
<img onclick="SwapImage('zoom',this);" alt="" title="" class="" style="opacity: 1;" src="/ws/ws.dll/QPic?SN=68942&amp;P=545662227&amp;PX=100&amp;ReqFrameSize=1&amp;I=1">
```

So the source of the first image is:

```
https://www.uspens.co/ws/ws.dll/QPic?SN=68942&P=545662227&PX=100&ReqFrameSize=1&I=1
```

While the source if the second image is:

```
https://www.uspens.co/ws/ws.dll/QPic?SN=68942&P=545662227&PX=100&ReqFrameSize=1&I=2
```

You can vary the Pixel-Size of the image by changing  the `PX-Value` inside this URL (currently it's PX=100)

So to get both images:

```
frame = urlopen("https://www.uspens.co/ws/ws.dll/PrDtl?UID=31818&SPC=wgftb-kzzro")
soup = BeautifulSoup(frame.read(), "html5lib")

#Product Image
images = soup.find_all("div", class_ = 'item')

for img in images:
    img_url = img.find("img")
    img_url = "https://www.uspens.co" + img_url["data-lazy"]
    print(img_url)
```

output:

```
https://www.uspens.co/ws/ws.dll/QPic?SN=68942&P=545662227&PX=100&ReqFrameSize=1&I=1
https://www.uspens.co/ws/ws.dll/QPic?SN=68942&P=545662227&PX=100&ReqFrameSize=1&I=2
```